# Hi, anyone met the sending issue like this? By using powershell

Tags: powershell

My script is about sending notfication email, and it was running well on my local machine, but when I removed it to an server 2k3, the email cannot be sent out with below error log:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was
 not authenticated"
At line:1 char:19
+ $smtp_buglist.Send <<<< ($mail_buglist)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Please help me out of this, I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked this out, the thing I need to do is to mark `$send.UseDefaultCredentials` as "True"

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.